# php списки, коллекции

Tags: php, база-данных, коллекции

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь

```
    foreach ($tickets -> result() as $row){
        $sqlPrice = $this -> db -> query("SELECT bilet_prices.price FROM bilet_prices JOIN circus ON bilet_prices.circus_id = circus.id
        WHERE circus.date = '{$v -> date}' AND bilet_prices.stadium_sector_id = '{$row->sector_name}'");
        $price = $sqlPrice -> row(0);
        $row->sector_name;
        $row->quantity;
        $price->price;
    }
```

Вот в этом коде я достаю данные с базы, потом в цикле фор ич достаю одно значения исходя из уже полученных (знаю костыль в каком то смысле жетский, но там настолько ужасно реализовано бд, что по другому не вытащить)

Так вот, мне хочется записать все эти данные в список, а потом ниже вывести этот список в html таблицу.

Спасибо.

Comment: А в чём проблема в этом же цикле записать в масив нужные, или вы предпологаете использовать коллекцию

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема записать в массив?

```
$result[] = ['price'=>$sqlPrice->row(0), 'sector_name'=>$row->sector_name, 'quantity'=>$row->quantity]
```